# Triangular rings with direct sums

Tags: ring-theory

In the Lam's book (*A first course in noncommutative rings*), 
he is representing the triangular ring with direct sum. 
I could not understand this part.
How can we consider the triangular rings with direct sums , while we don't have the same multiplicative operation? 
I have tried to think about an isomorphism between triangular rings and direct sums as bimodules, but this won't help me to understand the ideals.
Also, why do we need to consider the triangular ring by direct sum?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by representing a triangular ring with direct sum.

Comment: Triangular rings : 2x2 matrix , its entries are the rings R( ring ), M (R,S) bimodule, S(ring) and the direct sum of R + M + S

Comment: The direct sum is as abelian groups. Then you define a multiplication on the corresponding abelian group.

Comment: How, you mean individually. Could you clarify it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: The ideals of the triangular ring in terms of direct sum

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: The book says that R+M is an ideal of A.

Comment: And? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How can define an ideal by direct sum if it has different multiplicative operation.

Comment: $R \oplus M$ is a subgroup of $R \oplus M \oplus S$.

Comment: So , you mean that R+M isomorphic to the matrix of R M as additive subgroup, but the book defines a table of multiplication